# Intuition behind using the Cartesian product for finding number of unique BSTs

Tags: c++, algorithm, binary-search-tree

I am solving a LeetCode question.  The question is:

> Given `n`, how many structurally unique BSTs can be generated, that store the values from `1...n`?  For e.g., for `n=3`, a total of `5` unique BSTs can be generated as follows:

```
   1         3     3      2      1
    \       /     /      / \      \
     3     2     1      1   3      2
    /     /       \                 \
   2     1         2                 3
```

The maximum upvoted solution makes use of DP and the following recursive formula:

```
G(n) = G(0) * G(n-1) + G(1) * G(n-2) + … + G(n-1) * G(0)
```

where `G(n)` represents the number of unique BSTs that can be generated for `n`.  The code is as follows:

```
class Solution {
public:
    int numTrees(int n) {
        vector<int> G(n+1);
        G[0]=G[1]=1;

        for(int i=2; i<=n; i++)
            for(int j=1; j<=i; j++)
                G[i]+=G[j-1]*G[i-j];

        return G[n];
    }
};
```

While I more-or-less do understand what is going on, I didn't understand why we take a *Cartesian product* (instead of simple addition, which is more intuitive).  As per my understanding:

```
G[i] += G[j-1] * G[i-j];
```

should instead be:

```
G[i] += G[j-1] + G[i-j];  //replaced '*' with a '+'
```

This is so because, I think the number of unique BSTs possible with `i` as the current root should be the *sum*(?) of the number of BSTs for its left and right subtrees.  I did try a few examples but somehow the numbers get multiplied magically in the original solution (with a `*`) and the final answer appears in `G[n]`.

Could someone please provide an intuitive explanation for using Cartesian product instead of sum?

**Note:**  The original question is [here](https://leetcode.com/problems/unique-binary-search-trees/description/) and the solution is [here](https://discuss.leetcode.com/topic/8398/dp-solution-in-6-lines-with-explanation-f-i-n-g-i-1-g-n-i).  Also, the original code is in Java while I have posted the C++ variation that I wrote above.

Comment: Do you understand or I can try a different way or clarify things?

Comment: @coderredoc, thank you.  I got your point.  I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go by mathematical induction and then apply it to the sub-problems to get the result. Or simply just check for small values and then go for higher values.

For example:-

```
No of nodes      BST representation

1   -->    [1]

2   -->  [2]  [1]
         /     \
        [1]    [2]

3   -->  [1]
           \
           [2]
             \
             [3]

         [2]
         / \
        [1] [3]

          [3]
          /
       [2]
       /
      [1]
4  --> 
        [1]
      /     \
     NUM{}  NUM of keys with 3 val NUM{2,3,4}

      [2]
      /  \
    NUM{1} NUM{3,4}

      [3]
      /  \
    NUM{1,2} NUM{4}

          [4]
         /     \
    NUM{1,2,3}  NUM{}
```

From the 4th case you can clearly understand that we have to simply multiply the number of possible ways to group the left and right subtree in each of the trees. And for a given number of values we have to add them. That's why cartesian product is being used.

The product basically gives us all possible order the whole true can have. 
For example:

> `G[i] += G[j-1] * G[i-j];` Here `j-1` nodes are to the left( we can assume
>   without loss of generality) and `i-j` nodes to the right sub-tree. And
>   now you can arrange the left sub-tree in `G[j-1]` ways and similarly for
>   right sub-tree in `G[i-j]` ways. Now think how many ways can you arrange
>   the original tree which has this left and rigth subtree? It would
>   multiply. Because each combination of left and right subtree will give
>   rise to a unique tree representation.

This also explains why we define `G[0]=1` because it conforms to the way we do things here. And also the number of arrangements with no value is also an arrangement. So it is considered 1.